# empty ID after saving model to database

Tags: django

I have an "Images" model that has

```
 imageID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
```

Then I'm doing:

```
newimage = Images(status=1, createDateTime=datetime.now(), User=user)
newimage.save()
```

Then I'm trying to retrieve the imageID using newimage.imageID, but it's empty. Even after the row was added to the database.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've used an `IntegerField`, rather than an [`AutoField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#autofield), which implies that you're responsible for setting the value yourself rather than letting the database do it. Do you have any such code? If not, why have you used that field? Why not just use the automatic id field?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MSSQL Server, you can set the default valut of the primary key to NEWSEQUENTIALID() and the data type to UNIQUEIDENTIFIER.